# Stored-procedure is very slow

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I have the following `stored-procedure` in `SQL server`.

My code is the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[current_call]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @user_id nvarchar(128) 

    
AS
BEGIN
    SET FMTONLY OFF
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @LocUserId nvarchar(128)
    SET @LocUserId = @user_id

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT dbo.Call.call_id, dbo.Call.amb_id as ambulanceNum, dbo.Call.patient_number as patientId, dbo.Call.patient_age, dbo.Call.patient_sex as gender, dbo.Call.patient_phone, dbo.Call.caller_name, dbo.Call.call_received, dbo.Call.call_transfer, dbo.Call.call_response, dbo.Priority.name AS priorityName, dbo.Call_Status.name as Call_Status, 
                  dbo.Station.station_name, dbo.City.city_name, dbo.Protocol.name AS protocolName
FROM     dbo.City INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Call INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Priority ON dbo.Call.priority = dbo.Priority.priority_id ON dbo.City.city_id = dbo.Call.city INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Protocol ON dbo.Call.protocol_category = dbo.Protocol.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.Station INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Ambulance ON dbo.Station.station_id = dbo.Ambulance.ambulance_station ON dbo.Call.amb_id = dbo.Ambulance.ambulance_id
                  INNER JOIN
                  dbo.Call_Status ON dbo.Call.call_status = dbo.Call_Status.call_status_id

WHERE dbo.Call.user_id=@LocUserId and dbo.Call.call_status=2
    SET FMTONLY ON
END
```

[This is](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJHqEK4xv) the query plan.

Is there a way to make it to respond faster?

Comment: Post the query plan, using Paste the Plan. We're also going to likely need to the DDL of the involved tables and the related index. Seems like indexes is likely to be your problem.

Comment: Also, what's the point in the variable `@LocUserId` when it is literally set the value of `@user_id`? Why not just use `@user_id` in the `WHERE`?

Comment: Also, note it is advised to not use `SET FMTONLY OFF` as it has been replaced, as per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-fmtonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @Larnu, reassigning a parameter to a local variable is the old-school (but still effective) way to avoid parameter sniffing issues.

Comment: @Larnu I added the query plan. The indexes are only the PK of tables, those that contain `Id` in their name.